# Dropdown in twig not working with symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a proyect with symfony 2.8. When I add a dropdown on mi navbar in twig, is added correctly. But when I click on it the dropdown not drop... The url change adding the # of href, but this not dropdwon.

My code is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                       aria-expanded="false">  <img src="" height="40" width="40" class="profile-photo img-circle">
                        {{ app.user.username }} <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Edit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

How can implement this on twig to work??
Thanks!

Comment: You're probably missing the bootstrap JS files or not using the [dropdown plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) of it.

Comment: i added <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.js') }}"> </script> into my base.html.twig and I use {% extends '::base.html.twig' %} to import this. Is necessary add javascript too?

Comment: Did you get a bootstrap version with the dropdown functionality included? (It is by default) Also: Are you sure your `bootstrap.js` is in the `css/` folder? (eg. no 404 in the network tab of your browser?)